# Unnamed pipes in a chain of processes - C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I was wondering if it's possible to spawn a chain of processes (P0 forks P1, P1 forks P2, P2 forks P3, and so on..) where each (grand)child process has its own individual, unnamed pipe connecting him to the head of the chain, namely P0?

Let's assume that P0 acts as a sort of "manager" and sends instructions to these processes.
One could be added at the end of the chain or a particular process should be removed. At first  I thought of implementing a channel of pipes that connects P1-P2-P3-...-PN so that the message would propagate down the chain until the intended one. But passing through each process wouldn't be as efficient as having P0 directly send, for example, the instruction "FORK" to the *n*-th process.

```
                         ------------
                        | Process P0 |
                         ------------
         1) P0 forks P1 /       
and they share "pipe1" /        3) Here I need individual pipes P0-P2, P0-P3
                      /            until P0-PN
                     /
          ------------           ------------            ---            ------------
         | Process P1 |->forks->| Process P2 |->forks-> |...|->forks-> | Process PN |
          ------------           ------------            ---            ------------
                     2)P1 forks P2
```

Moreover, I'm not sure how forking and pipes would work together in this case. Since a child "inherits" the file descriptors of his father, I was wondering if the *n*-th child would have access to file descriptors of all *n-1* processes that come before him in the chain and so possibly read on those pipes too.

I'm not looking specifically for code as an answer, but an idea/algorithm on how to organize the creation of this chain (using only unnamed pipes), if it is indeed possible (as I believe). I'm new to C language and I'm trying to grasp concepts such as those here illustrated. I haven't found examples of pipes in such process structures, or at least none that could give me a hint on this specific case.

Comment: One way is to create an array of pipes in P0. Then each parent process tells its child which pipe to use by setting a variable before forking.